# why the picture gone after do the update data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

lets say i have 2 column in my inventory data called `category` and `image_name` in my php and database.

image_name are coming from this (basically in my database, image_name contain the link of the uploaded image) :

```
<?php


                    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                      $file = $_FILES['uploadgambar'];

                      $fileName = $_FILES['uploadgambar']['name'];
                      $fileTmpName = $_FILES['uploadgambar']['tmp_name'];
                      $fileSize = $_FILES['uploadgambar']['size'];
                      $fileError = $_FILES['uploadgambar']['error'];
                      $fileType = $_FILES['uploadgambar']['type'];


                      $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
                      $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

                      $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

                      if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
                        if ($fileError === 0) {
                          if ($fileSize < 5000000) {
                            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true) . "." . $fileActualExt;
                            $fileDestination = 'uploads/' . $fileNameNew;
                            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                            //  header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
                          } else {
                            echo "File anda terlalu besar (maximal 1gb)";
                          }
                        } else {
                          echo "Terdapat error dalam mengupload file";
                        }
                      } else {
                        echo "Anda tidak bisa upload file ini karena tidak berbentuk JPG/JPEG/PNG";
                      }
```

i build some code for update feature for category and image_name column like this

```
$kategori = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["kategori"]);
$image_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $fileDestination);
```

and here's for the update

```
   $sql1 = "update $tabeldatabase set kategori='$kategori', image_name = '$image_name' where kode = '$kode';

$updatean = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
                          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>  alert('Berhasil, Data barang telah diupdate!'); </script>";
                          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = '$forwardpage';</script>";
```

but the problem is, when i update the image its run, but when i update kategori, idk why my picture gone and when i look at the database, column image_name has removed for that id and cause the image gone.

my expected result is, just like update feature, if i update the category, then the image_name wont missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing your answer, but maybe it needs some editions. so add some comments if the ways not fix the problem.

one of the reasons maybe due to updating the row of database even if the file name is empty. so you must check the file name before update the database table record.

In this code, whenever you don't have upload file, so $fileDestination will be empty, so the cell of table will be empty and image address will gone!

For that problem, you could change the query:

```
$sql1 = "update $tabeldatabase set kategori='$kategori', image_name = '$image_name' where kode = '$kode';
```

to something like this:

```
if ($image_name) {
  $sql1 = "update $tabeldatabase set kategori='$kategori', image_name = '$image_name' where kode = '$kode';
} else {
  $sql1 = "update $tabeldatabase set kategori='$kategori' where kode = '$kode';
}
```

---

Apart from this I recommend you to change this row:

```
$sql1 = "update $tabeldatabase set kategori='$kategori', image_name = '$image_name' where kode = '$kode';
```

to a fixed table name like this:

```
$sql1 = "update my_static_table_name set kategori='$kategori', image_name = '$image_name' where kode = '$kode';
```

so you can easily debug the problem.

Comment: sorry i dont understand, you gave me 2 solutions?

Comment: your problem may be caused of many reasons. so you have to check step by step. so I gave you first step to check, if the problem is not fixed, let me know to find the problem.

Comment: sorry for the late response, but yea this has solved my problem, thank you very much. mark as an answer! anyway, i was wondering, why you prefer ```my_static_table``` over ```$tabeldatabase``` ?

Comment: because if you separate the table name like this, you can easily debug your codes. but you can use dynamic table name like $tabeldatabase and your code will work correctly.

Comment: And It will be perfect to choose this for best answer :D.

Comment: of course i already mark this as an answer, thank you anyway. have a good day